# MediaWiki - Hook to edit/alter page title on creation

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm looking to (programmatically) edit/alter the title of a page when its created and before its saved. I've tried a couple hooks to no avail. I can access the title being saved along with other info which ill be used to alter the title, but can not find the right call to save the altered title.

It is for a private/local lan wiki (currently MediaWiki version 1.38.1 ).

When a new article is created with in a certon category I want to number it with a prefix of #### - based on the number of articles already in the category. At the top of the category page itself I have a `<inputbox>` which pulls a template that has the wiki syntax for the category in it `[[Category:BlaBla]]`. When the article is saved I'm doing a check to make sure its a new article and some ofther checks for the info I need, which is working fine, but I can not save the new altered page name.

I've tried the following hooks to no avail.

```
onMultiContentSave
onArticlePrepareTextForEdit
```

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/MultiContentSave
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/ArticlePrepareTextForEdit

Heres acouple snippets ive been testing with, both do as i want, aside from saving the altered page name.

```php
    public static function onArticlePrepareTextForEdit( WikiPage $wikiPage, ParserOptions $parserOptions ) {

        return;

        $exists = $wikiPage->exists();
        if ($exists == 1) {
            #return true;
        }
        
        $getTitle = $wikiPage->getTitle();
        # check if title starts with 0000, exit if so, no work needs to be done
        if (self::titleCheck($getTitle)) {
            #return true;
        }

        $checkCategories = $wikiPage->getCategories();
        $inMalak = false;
        foreach ($checkCategories as $value) {
            if ($value == "Category:Malak") {
                $inMalak = true;
            }
        }

        if ($inMalak == 1) {
            $newTitle = self::newTitlePre() . $getTitle;
            #$wikiPage->setTitle($newTitle);
            print(">" . $newTitle . "<br>");
        }

        self::pr($newTitle);
    }

    public static function onMultiContentSave(RenderedRevision $renderedRevision, UserIdentity $user, CommentStoreComment $summary, $flags, Status $hookStatus){
        

        #return;

        $revision = $renderedRevision->getRevision();

        $getTitle = $revision->getPageAsLinkTarget();
        if (self::titleCheck($getTitle)) {
            return true;
        }

        #$titleOBJ = $revision->Title();
        $title = $revision->getId();
        $parent_id = $revision->getId();

        $content = $revision->getContent( SlotRecord::MAIN );
        $new_content = $content->getText();

        
        #$test = $revision->ParserOutput();

        $parent_id = "";
        if ($parent_id == "") {

            $pos = strpos($new_content, "[[Category:Malak]]");
            if ($pos) {
                $newTitle = self::newTitlePre() . $getTitle;
                #$wikiPage->setTitle($newTitle);
            }

        }

        self::pr($newTitle);

    }
```

EDIT........

Still have not found the proper way to do this, but came up with a work around (hackery) which works for my needs.

Using the [onEditFormPreloadText](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/EditFormPreloadText) hook, change the url and added a new parameter ('`MalakHere`'), edited the '`title`' parameter to the altered title, then do a redirect with the new page name. In the hook function there is a check for the '`MalakHere`' parameter, if found (only cause of redirect) then it will exit the function so not to create a loop.

```php
    public static function onEditFormPreloadText(string &$text, Title &$title ) {
        global $wgOut;

        if ( isset( $_GET["MalakHere"] ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        $pos = strpos($text, "[[Category:Malak]]");
        if ($pos) {
            $url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
            $urlTitle = urlencode($_GET["title"]);

            $newURL = str_replace("title=" . $urlTitle,"MalakHere=yes",$url);
            $newTitle = self::newTitlePre() . $title->prefixedText;
            $url = $newURL . "&title=" . $newTitle;

            return $wgOut->redirect($url);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the PHP code in its production form, without the debugging comments. Currently, your ` onArticlePrepareTextForEdit` function immediately and unconditionally returns, doing nothing.

Comment: Yes, its done on purpose so i can bounce between the two for testing. Do you know which Mediawiki class to call to re-set the article title before saving ?

Answer (score 0):

Still have not found the proper way to do this, but came up with a work around (hackery) which works for my needs.

Using the [onEditFormPreloadText](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/EditFormPreloadText) hook, change the url and added a new parameter ('`MalakHere`'), edited the '`title`' parameter to the altered title, then do a redirect with the new page name. In the hook function there is a check for the '`MalakHere`' parameter, if found (only cause of redirect) then it will exit the function so not to create a loop.

```php
    public static function onEditFormPreloadText(string &$text, Title &$title ) {
        global $wgOut;

        if ( isset( $_GET["MalakHere"] ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        $pos = strpos($text, "[[Category:Malak]]");
        if ($pos) {
            $url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
            $urlTitle = urlencode($_GET["title"]);

            $newURL = str_replace("title=" . $urlTitle,"MalakHere=yes",$url);
            $newTitle = self::newTitlePre() . $title->prefixedText;
            $url = $newURL . "&title=" . $newTitle;

            return $wgOut->redirect($url);
        }

        return true;
    }
```